# Sizing Ground wire for 200AFeeder to House

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, grounding

Im moving my service entrance from my house to a shop 75' away (in Tucson AZ, with TEP). The new service will be 400A (well 320/400) with the shop eating 200A and a backfeed to the house underground to its original panel (but moving the feed from overhead wire to underground).  This panel will have the ground bus and neutrals separated with 4 wires feeding the unit:
350 KCMIL AL for the HOTs, a 4/0 AL for the Neutral (using the 70% rule) and a #6 cu ground wire.
The wires are suitable for direct burial, but i'm encasing them in conduit anyways and burying at 36" depth.

So the question is:  the 6AWG Cu looks tiny compared to the massive current carrying conductors.  Did I interpret the NEC code incorrectly?

Here is the Result:  main Box with 4 wires for each feeder 350 350 4/0 and #6
[image]

Comment: For the new 400A main panel,  I am using #2 Cu to tie into several Grounding Rods. based on the size of the 400A feeds.  (which are 600KCMIL x3 AL)

Comment: I'm not sure why you need 250 kcmil.  Sine the now-backfeed line to the house serves an entire domicile, I would expect 310.15(B)(7) to kick in.  Now on that line from service to house, is there a ground wire?

Comment: The new feed will contain a ground in addition to the three power conductors. The lugs arw only 75C lugs.  Ambient can top 100f here, so I vacated the feed based on those factors... what I didnt do was run the normal residential. 83 multiplier because I thought feeder had to be rated to 125% of peak load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, you're interpreting the Code correctly

Table 250.122 in the NEC is what governs equipment grounding conductors, and for a feeder with a 200A maximum breaker ahead of it, it requires a 6AWG copper wire, which is what you are installing.  This is because the grounding conductor only has to carry current long enough for the breaker to trip; in normal operation, there should be 0 current on it, as opposed to the hots and neutral, which have to sing for their supper, 24/7/365.

Note that this is a *different* table from the table that's used to size *grounding electrode conductors* such as those going off to your ground rods.  Your 2AWG Cu GEC is a trifle undersized for 600 kcmil Al service conductors according to Table 250.66, which'd require 1/0AWG Cu for that application; however, since you're dealing only with ground *rods* and not a water pipe or miscellaneous electrode, NEC 250.66(A) kicks in and says that a 6AWG conductor is all that's needed.  (A concrete-encased electrode would fall under 250.66(B) which only requires a 4AWG conductor, and ground rings require no more than a 2AWG as NEC 250.66(C) requires the GEC to be no larger than the ring conductor, which is required to be 2AWG minimum by 250.52(A)(4).)

Comment: Thanks,  As to the Ground rods I've got two each with 2AWG  if that gets to the intent of 1/0 for grounding electrodes...  That #6 just looks out of place in the conduit with the giant Al wires.  Im glad I interrupted it correctly.

Comment: @markf -- well, the Code would have let you run 6AWG to those rods, so the 2AWG is fine :)